# What is the most efficient way of creating an object with a subset of properties, based on an array of property names in javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

In the following example (which does what I require), I'm looping the properties of an object, and creating a new object which has just the properties included in the selectedProperties array.

Is there a more efficient way to do this? I have looked at Object Destructuring, but I'm not sure how this applies if you have an array of resulting properties like this.

```
const bigObject = {
  prop1: "value1",
  prop2: "value2",
  prop3: "value3",
  prop4: "value4"
}

const selectedProperties = ['prop1', 'prop4'];

result = {};
Object.keys(bigObject).forEach((propertyName)=>{
    if(selectedProperties.includes(propertyName)){
        result[propertyName] = bigObject[propertyName];
  }
});

console.log(result);
```

Output:

```
{
  prop1: "value1",
  prop4: "value4"
}
```

Comment: I don't think destructuring can be used if the properties to be destructured are dynamic?

Comment: are your selected properties always in the given object?

Answer (score 1):

Don't loop over all the `Object.keys` and then filter them. Just loop over the properties that you want, and extract them from the object - each in `O(1)` time:

```
const result = selectedProperties.reduce((obj, prop) => {
    obj[prop] = bigObject[prop];
    return obj;
}, {});
```

Comment: If I answer this question, My answer would be exactly this...

Answer (score 0):

Just loop through your selected properties:

```js
const bigObject = {
  prop1: "value1",
  prop2: "value2",
  prop3: "value3",
  prop4: "value4"
}

const selectedProperties = ['prop1', 'prop4'];

let result = {};
selectedProperties.forEach(prop => {
  result[prop] = bigObject[prop];
});
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

Or using [`Object.fromEntries()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/fromEntries) and mapping the selectedProperties.

```
const result = Object.fromEntries(selectedProperties.map(prop => [prop, bigObject[prop]]));
```

Answer (score 0):

You could assign the new parts to an object and filter the given properties if necessary.

```js
const
    object = { prop1: "value1", prop2: "value2", prop3: "value3", prop4: "value4" },
    keys = ['prop0', 'prop1', 'prop4'],
    result = Object.assign({}, ...keys
        .filter(Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty, object)
        .map(k => ({ [k]: object[k] }))
    );

console.log(result);
```